# NHibernate - Query multiple tables with one query

Tags: c#, nhibernate, criteria

I'm using NHibernate 2, and I'd like to be able to do the following:

I have many DAO types.  They are all subclasses of `BaseDAO`, but they are not related in the NHibernate mappings at all.  (These subclasses dot not all have common properties.)

I want to write a method that will search all of my DAO types and return a `List<BaseDAO>` containing all matches.

The method signature should look something like:

```
public IList<BaseDAO> GlobalSearch(string searchTerm, int startIdx, int maxRows);
```

The query needs to check `searchTerm` against all `string` properties of the domain types.  We are currently doing this for one type at a time using a method that builds a `Disjunction` to search on all properties for a given type.

```
private Disjunction BuildDisjunction(string searchTerm, Type type)
```

I'd like to combine all of the disjunctions for all of my domain types and create one query that will return a list of the `BaseDAO`.

Here is what I have so far:

```
public IList<DomainBase> GlobalSearch(string searchTerm, 
                                      int startIndex, int maxRows)
{
    ICriteria crit = GetCriteria<BaseDAO>();
    foreach (Type t in GetAllDomainTypes())
    {
        Disjunction disj = BuildDisjunction(searchTerm, t);
        // somehow use this disjunction
    }
    crit
        .AddOrder(Order.Asc("DispName"))
        .SetFirstResult(startIdx)
        .SetMaxResults(maxRows);
    return crit.List<BaseDAO>(); ;
}
```

Is this possible?  How can I modify/complete the above method to achieve the functionality I need?

Comment: I don't think this is going to be possible. Think about how you would do this in SQL, if it's impossible to do in one SQL query, then it's going to be impossible to do in NHibernate.

Comment: @Vadim, that is kinda what I was afraid of.  Unfortunately my knowledge of SQL is too little to know if this is possible or not.

Comment: Are you searching on a property of the base class? If so then it would be possible to generate each query into a MultiCritera, execute it and populate all the results back into a list.

Comment: @Phill,could you show me how to do that?  But, no.  I'm searching on all public string properties of all subclasses.

Comment: Would probably need to do some reflection in order to do it, I get home from work in a few hours, I'll see if i can write up an example, see if it is in-fact possible, I'm 98% sure it is. Will let you know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This method will only work with MSSQL Server.**

Ok I've written the following, I hope it's what you're after, it can be refactored but it will get you started.

Given the following test classes:

```
public class BaseClass
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }   
}

public class TestClassOne : BaseClass
{
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
}

public class TestClassTwo : BaseClass
{
    public virtual string Value { get; set; }
    public virtual string Hobby { get; set; }
}

public class TestClassThree : BaseClass
{
    public virtual string Month { get; set; }
    public virtual int Day { get; set; }
}

public class TestClassFour : BaseClass
{
    public virtual string Title { get; set; }
    public virtual string Content { get; set; }
}
```

Can query the all those classes by reflecting them, then reflecting the properties which are a type of string.

```
        var session = new SessionFactoryManager().CreateSessionFactory().OpenSession();
        var criteria = session.CreateMultiCriteria();

        //Find classes that inherit from BaseClass
        var classses = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes().Where(x => x.BaseType == typeof(BaseClass));
        var searchValue = "Test";

        foreach (var classs in classses)
        {
            //Find all the properties that are typeof string
            var properties = classs.GetProperties()
                                   .Where(x => x.PropertyType == typeof(string));

            var query = DetachedCriteria.For(classs);

            foreach (var memberInfo in properties)
            {
                query.Add(Restrictions.InsensitiveLike(memberInfo.Name, searchValue, MatchMode.Anywhere));
            }

            criteria.Add(query);
        }

        var results = criteria.List()
                              .Cast<ArrayList>()
                              .ToList()
                              .SelectMany(x => x.ToArray())
                              .Cast<BaseClass>()
                              .ToList();

        foreach (var result in results)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(result.Id);
        }
```

Will generate a single query batch like so:

```
SELECT this_.Id   as Id1_0_,
       this_.Name as Name1_0_
FROM   TestClassOne this_
WHERE  lower(this_.Name) like '%test%' /* @p0 */


SELECT this_.Id    as Id3_0_,
       this_.Value as Value3_0_,
       this_.Hobby as Hobby3_0_
FROM   TestClassTwo this_
WHERE  lower(this_.Value) like '%test%' /* @p1 */
       and lower(this_.Hobby) like '%test%' /* @p2 */


SELECT this_.Id    as Id2_0_,
       this_.Month as Month2_0_,
       this_.Day   as Day2_0_
FROM   TestClassThree this_
WHERE  lower(this_.Month) like '%test%' /* @p3 */


SELECT this_.Id      as Id0_0_,
       this_.Title   as Title0_0_,
       this_.Content as Content0_0_
FROM   TestClassFour this_
WHERE  lower(this_.Title) like '%test%' /* @p4 */
       and lower(this_.Content) like '%test%' /* @p5 */
```

Comment: This looks promising.  I will take a look when I get a chance.  Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the help, and this looks like what I want.  However I'm getting this error - `The driver NHibernate.Driver.OracleClientDriver does not support multiple queries.`

Comment: @jjnguy - Oh bugger, this is a feature of SQLServer, Oracle doesn't support query batching :( then the answer to your original question is it isn't possible :(